# Как получить список элементов статистики таблицы в MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица у которой много элементов статистики. Я хочу удалить некоторые из них по части названия типа '%_24'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте подробностей в свой вопрос, желательно с примером вашего кода, который у вас не работает или работает не так, как вы хотите

Answer (score 1):

Сначала получаем список всех статистик по критерию и создаём скрипт удаления, потом его выполняем:

```
declare @t nvarchar(128) = N'dbo.Goods';
declare @sql varchar(max) = '';
select @sql = @sql + 'DROP STATISTICS ' + @t + '.' + [name] + ';'  + CHAR(13)+ CHAR(10) from  sys.stats where object_id = OBJECT_ID(@t) and [name] like '%_24'

print @sql;

EXEC (@sql);
```